# Removing deepin from update command

Tags: linux-mint, repository, deepin

I'm using Linux mint and when ever I run `sudo apt-get update` it updates but shows output down and I don't know if I should worry or ignore it either ways is there anyway to remove this "error"?

```
Ign:16 http://packages.linuxdeepin.com/deepin raring InRelease                                                                        
Err:17 http://packages.linuxdeepin.com/deepin raring Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:da8:d800:95::114 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.linuxdeepin.com/deepin raring Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a Red Hat/CentOS user, not Mint. I will share what I know.
There is a repository list in Unix that tells it where to look for updates. One of the places your system is configured to look is http://packages.linuxdeepin.com/deepin. Mint says that this location is missing some necessary information, so it is ignoring it.
Thus, there is no harm to your system, unless you really NEED something from deepin.

It could also be that the deepin repository isn't configured correctly. Notice the "raring" message. Have a look at this URL: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=156447

Here are some instructions for removing a repository, which, I believe, is your original question. https://askubuntu.com/questions/43345/how-to-remove-a-repository